# Set value on ViewController from UrlScheme

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm struggling to prefill a textfield when I launch the app with my url scheme. When the app is launched without already being in memory, the value is not being set (or I think overruled by `viewDidLoad` or similar).

The boiled down path I'm taking looks like this:

```
// AppDelegate.m
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[[application keyWindow] rootViewController];

    MainViewController *main = (MainViewController *)[nav topViewController];

    [main setLabelText:@"this should be shown on screen"];

    return YES;
}
```

With a `ViewController` sitting in a `UINavigationController`

```
// MainViewController.m
@interface MainViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.someLabel.text = @"this is actually shown on screen";
}

- (void)setLabelText:(NSString *)text
{
    self.someLabel.text = text;
}

@end
```

So the label shows "this is actually shown on screen", not the text I set in `AppDelegate`. When setting breakpoints its fairly obvious why, I think, because `viewDidLoad` is called after `setLabelText`.

Is there a more robust path to prefilling text fields from a custom url scheme I'm missing?

Comment: You could use an NSNotification when the app is running in background, to let your ViewController know, when your app was opened using the custom url scheme.

Comment: The "already running" case is working fine for my shipping app (not in the simple spike project though, no idea why). It's the "fresh launch" thats causing trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[[application keyWindow] rootViewController];

    MainViewController *main = (MainViewController *)[nav topViewController];
    main.view;

    [main setLabelText:@"this should be shown on screen"];

    return YES;
}
```

The view is lazy loaded so it will load the first time it is needed.

Comment: I guess you're both right, but this did the trick. Watch out when fiddling with this, when you attach the debugger after manually launching the app, as you kind of need to do to when checking if things work with url schemes, running the app did not always run the most current code. Thats why my initial try `main.view.hidden = NO;` as I do in some tests SEEMED not to work because the simulator ran old code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that `setLabelText:` is called from the app delegate prior to the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method being called. What you'll need to do is keep a copy of the string in a property on the view controller then set that on the the label in `viewDidLoad`:

Header:

```
@interface MainViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringToSet;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.stringToSet) {
        self.someLabel.text = self.stringToSet;
    } else {
        self.someLabel.text = @"Some default string";
    }
}

@end
```

App Delegate:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[[application keyWindow] rootViewController];

    MainViewController *main = (MainViewController *)[nav topViewController];

    [main setStringToSet:@"this should be shown on screen"];

    return YES;
}
```